# Python TCP packets to be sent are combined

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to send TCP packets using socket in Python, and I can successfully send packets outside, I can see them using WireShark. However, as you can see that inside the while loop the code wait for `ENTER` key to be entered in order to send a packet. When I press ENTER one by one, I can see that my data (18 byte starts with 0xEFEB000000 in bytearray format) which is read from file, but not given here because I think it unnecessary and confusing, is sent packet by packet as I wanted. However, when I press and hold the ENTER button, it consecutively sends packets way faster than one by one. In this case, I can see in WireShark that some of the data are combined into a single TCP packet. I do not want this, and this is very strict unfortunately. How can I force socket to send the payload I gave packet by packet separately?

from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CLIENT_SOCK = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    CLIENT_SOCK.connect(("192.168.1.10", 42000))
 
    while True:
        input("Press ENTER to send a TCP packet...")
        # some file IO here to construct data variable,
        # 18 byte bytearray format. starts with 0xEFEB000000
        CLIENT_SOCK.sendall(data)
```

[image: Single Packet with single payload]

Single Packet with single payload

[image]

Single Packet with 5 payloads combined

Comment: Yup, that's how it works. TCP doesn't really have packets. It's your job to deal with it.

Comment: So, how can I deal with it? I need to send exactly 18 bytes of payload each time (which I am feeding the sendall method).

Comment: Buffer the data and extract 18 bytes.  Treat reading a socket similar to a file.  You can wrap the socket in a `socket.makefile` object then `.read(18)` will read exactly 18 bytes (unless the socket is closed early)

Comment: @MarkTolonen do you mean in the receiver side? If yes, isn't there a way to do that in the sender side? If not, can you elaborate a little bit please.

Comment: Yes, on the receiver side.  The sender just "puts bytes in the pipeline".  TCP isn't message-based.

Comment: Packets don't matter to TCP, because there's no way for the application to read just one packet at a time. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol.

Comment: @efe373 if you know every "packet" is 18 bytes then why don't you read 18 bytes at a time in the receiver?

Comment: @user253751 Because `s.recv(18)` can return < 18 bytes.

Comment: then you also need to receive the rest.

Comment: @user253751 because receiver side is an SoC running baremetal LwIP, and because the ethernet packet header (14 bytes) is not DWORD aligned it makes my DMA work slower. So, I inserted two bytes (EFEB) and just ignore it. But, in case TCP sends combined packets, I have to do more which I do not want to honestly.

Comment: @efe373 then your protocol is not TCP and you have no reason to pretend it is TCP. Considered using UDP instead? by the way, the IP header can get bigger or smaller, so can the TCP header!

Comment: @user253751 I need the ordering between packets. That was why I choose TCP over UDP. It was okay until the requirements of the project changed unfortunately. I need a fast communication (fastest possible) and, as I understood now, message protocol. Any recommendation?

Comment: Recommendation: accept the fact that TCP packets don't come aligned by themselves, and you can't force them to be aligned

Comment: Regarding the return, that is very likely a keyboard/OS issue.  Regarding sending the data immediately, that is not entirely possible due to the nature/intent of TCP (sounds like you want UDP?).  However, if you do not exceed the TCP transmit, receive, or congestion windows, then you can try setting the TCP PSH flag (but some OSs do not handle it correctly).  See https://packetlife.net/blog/2011/mar/2/tcp-flags-psh-and-urg/ for a discussion of this flag.

Answer (score 2):

TCP isn't message-based.  It just returns the bytes written into the socket in the order sent, but due to network buffer can break the bytes up in whatever packets it chooses.  Wrap the receiver in a `socket.makefile` object which will buffer read data, then `.read(n)` will read exactly *n* bytes unless the socket closes early.  Example:

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', 5000))
s.listen()
c, a = s.accept()

# 'with' will close the client socket and makefile object
# when it exits.
with c, c.makefile('rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(18)
        if not data:
            break
        print(data)
```

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
s.sendall(b'abcdefghijklmnopqr')
s.sendall(b'abc')
s.sendall(b'defghijklm')
s.sendall(b'nopqr')
s.sendall(b'abcdefghijklm')
s.sendall(b'nopqrabcdefghijklm')
s.sendall(b'nopqr')
s.close()
```

Server output:

```
b'abcdefghijklmnopqr'
b'abcdefghijklmnopqr'
b'abcdefghijklmnopqr'
b'abcdefghijklmnopqr'
```

Note: This *may* appear to work with a direct `c.recv(18)` **but** in a busy/complex network environment can fail to receive 18 bytes every time.